# How to block processing of HTML file while an external files is being downloaded?

Tags: html, sockets, webserver, esp8266

I am programming a webserver on an ESP8266 chip. The webserver loads a file named *index.html* when I try to open its homepage. This file contains links to several *.js* and *.css* files. From what I've read HTML files are processed sequentially. When the line containing the link to an external file is encountered, the client opens up a separate socket to the server and the file starts downloading. Meanwhile the client carries on processing the HTML file. So while loading the homepage the client opens several sockets, one for each file, and they are downloaded in parallel. This is causing the webserver to be overwhelmed with data, and the page doesn't load completely sometimes because the sockets are being prematurely closed down either by the client or by the server. Is there a way to halt the processing of a HTML page while a file is being downloaded, and continue once the file has been completely downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this may be a very simplistic view (and apologies if I misunderstood the requirements) - are you not able to combine all the js and CSS files into one minified (for each)? Once that is done, you can load the css along with the HTML file and then the JS files.